# how to keep radio button checked after refreshing page

Tags: php, html

my question is how can I keep the radio button checked after I miss filling one of the form fields?
I have a form for the admin to fill out to add a user, I have 3 radio buttons to choose user type, and of course, the rest of the form: user name, age, etc. when the user misses filling one of the fields and click submit, the filled information stay but the radio button get back to the old selection. how can I keep the new selection when correcting the form?
this is my code

نوع المستخدم
                    
                    
                         مدير

```
                    <input class="margin-radio" type="radio" value="clerk" name="usertype"> مساعد مدير

               
               
                    <input class="margin-radio" type="radio" value="client" name="usertype"> عميل
              
              
            </div>
            <!-- ------------- -->
            <div class="all-input">
                <label for="">الاسم الاول:</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) echo $_POST['firstname'];?>" required>
            </div>
            <!-- ------------ -->
            <div class="all-input">
                <label for="">الاسم الأخير:</label>
                <input type="text"  name="lastname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) echo $_POST['lastname'];?>" required>
            </div>
            <!-- ------ -->
            <div class="all-input">
                <label for="">البريد الالكتروني:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email'];?>" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Checked](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) attribute of the `<input type="radio"`

For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" <?php if(isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] == 'bar') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
```

This method also works for the `type="checkbox"` In that case you would need to iterate over the array of possible values.